# Why Doesn't My Heroku Application Connect?

Tags: heroku, postman

When I try to run my heroku app, drjs-myflix-app.herokuapp.com from Postman, I get an unexpected response:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {var p = ".eJwlzEEKgCAQheG7zFIy910mZBrTypRRoYju3ki774fHe6BxgAkMDGB5LUIRkyMm_sOnUufTRpJceCs63u4Il7Y5j5647akLU-wXiJSrDJVR8H5N0x2M:1mELUg:dL-ILNhbPqx2qTfENuqB8R43YZw", as = "http://drjs-myflix-app.herukoapp.com/mtm/async/";function d(n){window.location.href = "http://www42.herukoapp.com/"+n;}function ar(r) {if (r.slice(0, 1) !== ".") {try {window.location.assign(r);} catch (err) {}try {var mar = document.createElement("meta");mar.httpEquiv = "refresh";mar.content = "0;url="+r;document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(mar);} catch (err) {}} else {var s = document.createElement("span");s.id="ecode";s.appendChild(document.createTextNode(r.slice(1)));document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(s);}}if ("fetch" in window) {try {fetch(as + p + "/1", {credentials: "include"}).then(function(r) {if (!r.ok) {throw Error("50x");}return r.text();}).then(function(r) {ar(r);});} catch (err) {d(2);}} else {try {var x = new XMLHttpRequest();x.open("GET", as + p + "/2", false);x.onerror = function() {d(3);};x.onload = function() {if (x.status === 200) {ar(x.responseText);} else {d(4);}};x.onreadystatechange = function(r) {if (x.readyState === 4){if (x.status === 200) {ar(x.responseText);} else {d(6);}}};x.send();} catch (err) {d(5);}}})();
    </script>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh"
        content="5;url=http://drjs-myflix-app.herukoapp.com/mtm/direct/.eJwlzEEKgCAQheG7zFIy910mZBrTypRRoYju3ki774fHe6BxgAkMDGB5LUIRkyMm_sOnUufTRpJceCs63u4Il7Y5j5647akLU-wXiJSrDJVR8H5N0x2M:1mELUg:dL-ILNhbPqx2qTfENuqB8R43YZw/1" />
</head>

<body></body>

</html>
```

When I access the app on Firefox, I get the app's expected greeting, "Welcome to Dr. Levi's movie application!..." but I can't request any other endpoint. Can anyone help? The code I've pushed into it can be found at https://github.com/drjlevi6/E2.10-DataSecurity. Thank you!

Comment: What other endpoints does not work? What is the error?

Comment: (My) Response Codes
0 succeeds
1 javascript
2 hangs
3 empty
4 "405 Not Allowed"

Responses by endpoint (M = movies, U = username):
1 GET /users: 1,2
2 GET /users/U: 2
3 GET /M/genre/movieTitle: 2
4 GET /M/genre/name/genreName: 2
5 GET /M/director/name: 1
6 GET /M: 1
7 GET /M/name: 1
8 GET /: 0
9 GET /documentation: 0
10 POST /users/U: 1
11 PUT /users/U/newname: 4
12 POST /users/U/M/movieID: 
13 DELETE /users/U/movies/movieID: 4
14 DELETE /users/U/: 4

In Firefox/Chrome:
"Error: MongooseError: Operation `movies.find()` buffering timed out after 10000ms"

Comment: Additional response: 'Error: MongooseError: Operation `users.find()` buffering timed out after 10000ms'

Comment: SOLVED: Bad connection string ("CONNECTION URI") in the heroku app: didn't match the corresponding connection uri in MongoDB Atlas. Thank you for helping.